# Avoid returning result set from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, resultset

Assume I have some stored procedure (and I can't change it) which is returning a result set:

```
create procedure test_procedure
as
begin

    select 1

end
```

I know that I can insert result set into table, so it would be hidden to the calling code:

```
declare @t table(i int)

insert into @t
exec test_procedure
```

Are there any other ways to hide returning result set from the calling code?

**Updated**

It looks like I've been a bit confusing. I'm looking only for T-SQL answers (not .NET ones).

Comment: What exactly is the problem with returning this result set? You can always ignore the result set and let the garbage collector take care of it.

Comment: @Cylon Cat RE "let the garbage collector take care of it" that's not even the case. TDS is a streaming protocol ... if you don't _read_ the result, it won't necessarily be returned to the client. Even if parts of it are returned to the client, they would arguably be handled in native code, unless read with DataReader et al.

Comment: Cylon Cat: What if I cannot ignore the result set? e.g. code that calls my procedure assumes that no result set is returned.

Comment: Is there an actual error, or is this a matter of premature optimization?

Comment: @OMQ Honestly, why do people always second guess any question here? I believe there is a valid cause - for example if the client SHOULD execute some logic BUT NOT SEE something which the procedure happens to return ... do you _have_ to make a second proc or can you do it properly without?

Comment: @Toxic, you can always close the reader, can't you? Are you truly stuck reading the whole thing? @Andrew, you said you couldn't change the stored procedure, but you didn't say that you couldn't change the code that calls it. Either you can change that code, or you can write an alternative piece of code that throws away the result, or if you truly can't do anything about it at all, then assign the problem to someone who can.

Comment: @Cylon Cat, actually the question is about HOW to modify the code that calls the procedure :)

Comment: @Andrew Ah ... call `Command.ExecuteNonQuery` (which will not read the resultset) or `Command.Cancel` (if you only want to read parts of the result set). As I said before, TDS is streaming protocol, using ExecuteNonQuery will result in not having the full result set returned to the client (if the resultset is small it might I believe)

Comment: @Toxic, that gets to the heart of the issue. It's not a SQL question, it's an ADO.NET question. And you have two ways to solve it, in ADO.NET. On the other hand, if the result set is truly small, then this is all much ado about nothing.... er, premature optimization.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm looking only for SQL answers, not .NET ones. By calling code I meant another stored proc, or some sql batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no other solution. However, you should refactor your procedure to do only what you need. If you need the output for other calls, try to split the procedure into two.

Answer (score 1):

Use optional Output Parameter.

or use below case

```
Create procedure Check @c int
as
begin
if @c = 1
    select 1
else
    print 1 
end
```

write any condition that will satisfy and that returns you specified values.
use that parameter as optional so no other change in your procedure will come.

Answer (score 0):

Would you rather try to return your data through an output parameter, and return a status code as the procedure's return value?

You couldn't easily return a full resultset through that output parameter, but you could return some delimited data in a format of your choosing.

Comment: As I said I can't change stored procedure which returns result set.

Comment: Could you wrap it in another procedure you have control over?  Your wrapper could throw away the resultset.