# Return single result set from multi result set

Tags: sql-server

I created a following test stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestA]  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #MyTableA (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255))
    CREATE TABLE #MyTableB (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255))

    ..............

    EXEC TestB;
    SELECT * FROM #MyTableB;

END
```

The TestB stored procedure returns a result set. But I need to call it. According to this stored procedure, the two result sets are returned. But I need to return one. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are the tables related to each other ? Use join to retrieve the columns from both the tables

Comment: No related. The tables are different.

Comment: Then use union all to retrieve the data

Comment: No I want to return only #TableB. Not return #TableA.

Comment: So.. remove `select * from #MyTableA`?

Comment: That is a sample. It is instead of stored procedure. The stored procedure return a result set. I change my question. Please check it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Avoid returning result set from stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329777/t-sql-avoid-returning-result-set-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: See the technique in the linked question. Looks like you have to `exec` it into a table variable or temp table to avoid returning it.

Comment: Maybe you could try using a user-defined function instead of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestB]  
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 CREATE TABLE #MyTableA (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255))
 CREATE TABLE #MyTableB (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255))

 .............

 INSERT INTO #MyTableA
 exec TestA
 DROP TABLE #MyTableA
 SELECT * FROM #MyTableB;

END
```

Comment: I can't drop MyTableA. It is actually existed as a real table not temp table.

Comment: but you have defined in your question as temporary table and why are you creating that table in SP if it already exists ?? Anyways just remove Drop syntax